# Adding Cookies to a simple function

Tags: javascript

I need to add cookies so that when one div is open (showing) and the user clicks refresh it remmber the the last state.

I know it should be easy but im a total noob at js script and have been scrathing more than my head over this one. Any help would be more than appreciated. I have looked though different examples on this forum but they are complectaed and not clear. Looking for a simple solution to a simple bit of code. Thank you!

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('a.row_view').click(function() {
        $('.contentPadd.r_view').css('display', 'block');
        $('.contentPadd.l_view').css('display', 'none')
        $('.contentPadd.t_view').css('display', 'none');
    });
    $('a.list_view').click(function() {
        $('.contentPadd.r_view').css('display', 'none') //horizontal
        $('.contentPadd.l_view').css('display', 'block') //list
        $('.contentPadd.t_view').css('display', 'none') //thumbnails
    });
    $('a.table_view').click(function() {
        $('.contentPadd.r_view').css('display', 'none')
        $('.contentPadd.l_view').css('display', 'none')
        $('.contentPadd.t_view').css('display', 'block')
    });
});                                    
</script>

<a class="row_view">1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="list_view">2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="table_view">3</a>

<div class="contentPadd r_view">NUMBER 1</div>
<div class="contentPadd t_view">NUMBER 2</div>
<div class="contentPadd l_view">NUMBER 3</div>
```

Comment: #1 hit on google http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cookie handler that you can find here: http://forrst.com/posts/JavaScript_cookie_handler-JE9

To use it, create a new instance of the `Ovenmitts` object. Then, pass in two parameters to the `bakeCookie` method: name and value. Within your `click` function, do the following:

```
$('a.row_view').click(function() {
  var cookieObj = new Ovenmitts();
  cookieObj.bakeCookie('opened', 'a.row_view');
  $('.contentPadd.r_view').css('display', 'block');
  $('.contentPadd.l_view').css('display', 'none')
  $('.contentPadd.t_view').css('display', 'none');
});
```

Then, on page load, call the `admireCookie` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cookieObj = new Ovenmitts();
  var cookie = cookieObj.admireCookie('opened');
  if (cookie === 'a.row_view') {
    $('.contentPadd.r_view').css('display', 'block');
    $('.contentPadd.l_view').css('display', 'none')
    $('.contentPadd.t_view').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Let me know if you have any issues implementing this.

Also, instead of `.css('display', 'block')` and `.css('display', 'none')` you can use the jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` functions.

You can overwrite the cookie by calling the `bakeCookie` method and passing in the same name (e.g. 'opened'). That way, you can pass in a value to it to remember which drawer is open.

Comment: Tried and failed to implement. do you need two seprate sets of js script? - soory im a total noob, also if you use the jquery .show and .hise does the syntax need to be contained within the the div?

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` change the CSS `visibility` and `display` to `visible` or `hidden`, respectively. e.g. If `display: none`, it will change the inline style for the element to `display: block`.

Comment: You'll need to include the `Ovenmitts` object in your js. You can include that in a separate file if you wish.

Comment: I have used the show and hide as you mentioned as shown in the above post - have not figured out the how to iplement the post, can you help further? Please

Comment: Yes. Give me about 30 minutes and I'll try to walk you through it.

Comment: Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbaJz/1/

It will show you how it works. Copy the `var Ovenmitts` object (the whole thing up until it closes at `};`) and paste it into a new JS document. From there, within your `$(document).ready(function(){` paste the `var cookieObj`, etc, into each `click` function.

Comment: Great! I'm happy to be of assistance :)

Comment: There are always ways to simplify, although I do not recommend altering the `Ovenmitts` object. You can do a `switch case` statement for each of the elements you want to show/hide. `switch(cookie) { case 'a.row_view': // do something break; case 'a.list_view': //do something break;` etc.

Comment: Nick is it possible to detect if a cookie esists when the page is first loaded, if not then it defaults to a cookie that is derived by a php statement.. or to that effect. the above code is fine but when the page is first loaded it displays all three divs until a button is pressed, subsequently the cookie is set and all is ok.

Comment: Do you have a default state for which divs are hidden and shown?

Comment: how to set a default sate? my code is the above. I would like to be able to set the default state (on page load for ther first time) via php. I mean, i have 3 layouts. to set the php to default to either of the three layouts (div show/hide) when the user first loads the page. then when they select another layout the cookie is stored, when the page is reloaded (keeping the cookie in the cahe) it will go to their last layout.

Comment: my php looks defulat request looks like this:    if (DISPLAY_PRODUCT_LISTING_LAYOUT == 'thumbnail'){echo $prod_list_contents;}
      if (DISPLAY_PRODUCT_LISTING_LAYOUT == 'horizontal'){echo $prod_list_contents_horizontal;}
   if (DISPLAY_PRODUCT_LISTING_LAYOUT == 'list'){echo $prod_list_contents_list_a;}

Comment: i think i have got it or boggded it:
if(document.cookie.search("opened") > -1) {
 //alert("VISTIED BEFORE");
    var allcookies = document.cookie;
      cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');
      // Now take key value pair out of this array
      for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
         name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
         value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
      }
     document.cookie = (name + "=" + value);


} else {
document.cookie = "opened= <?php echo $DEFAULT_LAYOUT .';'?>";
//alert("NEW PERSON ARRIVING ON SITE!");
}

Comment: You can use my Ovenmitts objects to get this information more simply. Call the method `admireCookie()` on your new instance. `var handler = new Ovenmitts(); var cookie = handler.admireCookie('opened'); if (cookie !== null) { // has visited } else handler.bakeCookie('opened', '<?php echo $DEFAULT_LAYOUT; ?>');`

Comment: You don't need to `for` loop that iterates through all of the site's cookies. You only need the cookie named 'opened'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nick.

1. create or add this to your .js file:

   > //cookie handler for listing layouts // to instantiate a new object,
   >   create a variable and call the new operator // e.g. var myCookie = new
   >   Ovenmitts(); // then you can access the methods of Ovenmitts through
   >   myCookie.bakeCookie(), etc. var Ovenmitts = function() {   var ctx =
   >   this;   // create a cookie   // accepts 3 parameters: name, value,
   >   days   // cookie takes a key / value pair for name / value, expires /
   >   days   // days is optional, defaults to session end   ctx.bakeCookie =
   >   function(name, value, days) {
   >       if ( days ) {
   >         var date = new Date();
   >         date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   >         var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString(); 
   >       } else { var expires = ""; }
   >       return document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";   };   // reads a cookie   // accepts the name parameter (
   >   first value in the cookie )   ctx.admireCookie = function(name) {
   >       var nameEQ = name + '=';
   >       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   >       for ( var i = 0; i < ca.length; i += 1 ) {
   >         var c = ca[i];
   >         while (c.charAt(0) === ' ' ) { c = c.substring(1, c.length); }
   >         if ( c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0 ) { return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length); }
   >       }
   >       return null;   }; }; //end of cookie handler.
   >
   > $(document).ready(function(){      //Product listing layout div switch
   >     $('a.row_view').click(function() {       var cookieObj = new
   >   Ovenmitts();
   >                 cookieObj.bakeCookie('opened', 'a.row_view');
   >         $('.contentPadd.r_view').show();
   >             $('.contentPadd.l_view').hide();
   >             $('.contentPadd.t_view').hide();    });
   >
   > $('a.list_view').click(function() {         var cookieObj = new
   >   Ovenmitts();
   >                 cookieObj.bakeCookie('opened', 'a.list_view');      $('.contentPadd.r_view').hide();//horizontal
   >         $('.contentPadd.l_view').show(); //list
   >         $('.contentPadd.t_view').hide(); //thumbnails   });
   >     $('a.table_view').click(function() {        var cookieObj = new
   >   Ovenmitts();
   >                 cookieObj.bakeCookie('opened', 'a.table_view');         $('.contentPadd.r_view').hide();        $('.contentPadd.l_view').hide();
   >         $('.contentPadd.t_view').show();    });   var cookieObj = new
   >   Ovenmitts();   var cookie = cookieObj.admireCookie('opened');   if
   >   (cookie === 'a.row_view') {
   >         $('.contentPadd.r_view').show();
   >             $('.contentPadd.l_view').hide();
   >             $('.contentPadd.t_view').hide();   }   var cookieObj = new Ovenmitts();   var cookie = cookieObj.admireCookie('opened');   if
   >   (cookie === 'a.list_view') {
   >         $('.contentPadd.r_view').hide();//horizontal
   >         $('.contentPadd.l_view').show(); //list
   >         $('.contentPadd.t_view').hide(); //thumbnails   }
   >       var cookieObj = new Ovenmitts();   var cookie = cookieObj.admireCookie('opened');   if (cookie === 'a.table_view') {
   >         $('.contentPadd.r_view').hide();        $('.contentPadd.l_view').hide();
   >         $('.contentPadd.t_view').show();   } //END Product listing layout
   >   div switch
2. added this to my test.html page. Also add the js file:

> ```
>     <script language="javascript" src="YOURJSFILE.js"></script>
>    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js.js"></script>
>
> <a class="row_view">TEST 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
> <a class="list_view">TEST 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
> <a class="table_view">TEST 3</a>
> ```

1. added this to to my test.html page

> ```
> <div class="contentPadd r_view">TEST 1</div>
> <div class="contentPadd t_view">TEST 2</div>
> <div class="contentPadd l_view">TEST 3</div>
> ```

THATS IT. - ADD TO PHP -ADD IMAGES - EXPAND - Etc.